# In JQuery, how to read the element in focus right now?

Tags: jquery, focus, onblur

There is one text input field and one button.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onblur="saveValue();" />    
<input type="button" id="myButton" />
```

On Blur event ( input field ), a function ( saveValue) is called. I do not want to call that function if the current focus is the button (myButton).

How can I do it in JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably do this, because one element is blurred before the next is focused.  The closest approximation would be to set a timeout that you clear if the button is focused:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;

    $('input').blur(function(){
        timer = setTimeout(saveValue, 100);
    });

    $('#myButton').focus(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if(!$('#myButton').is(':focus'))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've missed something, but why not just bind the blur event to the input field only:

```
$("#yourInputId").live("blur", function()
{
  saveValue();
});
```

Comment: It seems this is what the OP is already doing (the function is not bound to the blur event on the button).

Comment: Yeah the OP was changed, similar to what I was suggesting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try..

```
$(':focus').each(function(){    
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'myButton'){
     //do stuff here
   } 
});
```

This [post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-the-focus-selector-valid) at the jquery forum suggests that this works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Here is my attempt:
Create the css class for the input text and use jquery to refer it that way.

Here is the code sample:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" class="input-text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('.input-text').blur(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //Call function save value by passing the reference of the current object
    SaveValue($this);
  });
});
</script>
```